# What's it called when someone does his work at client's home

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

People of some occupations usually do their work at the specifically equipped facilities.
For example, you go to the barbershop to get a haircut or you go to the dentist, when you have a tooth pain.

At some occasions, however, these professionals could arrange the service on your site (at your home, for example).

What's this kind of service / action called?

**UPDATE:** I am researching this particularly for barbers and have found "on-demand" term being used for this service.

> Barbers are available on-demand or you can schedule up to a week in advance

My second question is, whether "on-demand" is commonly in use for the barbers? If so, what other occupations it might be used for?

Comment: Making a house call?  working on-site or on-premises?

Comment: **In-house** staff, perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A doctor or other professional visiting someone's home to perform services is  a ["house call"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_call).

Comment: Thank you @Chris. That's the term I am going to use. Making the answer as an accepted one.

Answer (score 3):

Consider ***peripatetic***

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/peripatetic
    ADJECTIVE

> 1. Travelling from place to place, in particular working or based in various places for relatively short periods:
>      *the peripatetic nature of military life*
>      
>      1.1 (Of a teacher) working in more than one school or college:
>      *a peripatetic music teacher*

Also, ***mobile*** : a mobile hairdresser, for example, is one who visits their clients' homes.

Comment: Mobile is a very common term (+1).  Although one doesn't oft hear of a mobile doctor.

Comment: @Ste I just remembered the phrase "flying doctor", used in Australia for example, where in some regions people might live too far away from a hospital/doctors surgery to travel to it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Flying_Doctor_Service_of_Australia

Comment: Ah - yeah.  I recall that now too.  Although now we need to try to justofy flying hairdresser!

Comment: @Max Williams "flying doctor" is an interesting thing to know! The *Adj.* you posted are not exactly what I was looking for, but yet would help in the future. I am making other answer as an accepted one, because that term is most close to what I need. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  To continue on the Flying Doctor theme, many countries have "air ambulances", ie helicopters which can quickly get doctors and medical equipment to the scene of an accident.  Not many countries, though, have doctors who routinely travel to patients' **homes** by plane or helicopter for *elective*, ie non-emergency, care.  Australia is an exception I think because of its vast, sparsely populated interior.

Comment: @MaxWilliams while researching more, I found **on-demand** term. Usage Example: *Barbers are available on-demand or you can schedule up to a week in advance*. What do you think about it?

Comment: @EugeneDubinin to me, on-demand doesn't necessarily mean that they will come to your house - it might mean that you can access them whenever you want (eg in the middle of the night, but you still have to go to them).

Answer (score 1):

Though not generally associated with medical professionals, the idea of a technician or other professional doing their work at a place other than their office is often called a

**Service Call** ([TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/service+call))

Comment: this is a good term which is well suited for the technician and it is very helpful to know that. thank you.